# Alternative way to load DB driver in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there any other way to load DB driver than **class.forName**?

Comment: Removed "oracle" tag, because the question applies to JDBC in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modern JDBC drivers are supposed to provide enough metadata in their jar file manifest, so you may not need to do anything.

The main point of `Class#forName` is to remove the compile-time dependency on the particular JDBC driver (and make it configurable at run-time). If you are using Oracle driver code in your program anyway (to use their non-standard JDBC extensions) and have no compulsions to hardcode the driver class name, you can also just create a regular instance of the driver class.

```
 new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
```

Comment: Damn, i was just about to write that :), but it is not the manifest file where they are registered.

Comment: Thilo, I didn't see that working too, before. But I believe this is fixed in Java 1.6, because I just checked and it works. +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 9):

Modern Drivers don't need to be registered, because they have a **META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver** file that declares the existence of the driver, by containing the name of the Driver class.

Just use `DriverManager.getConnection(...)`, and it discovers the driver itself.

---

**EDIT** @Thilo: I just tested it with PostgreSQL, and it works:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class JdbcDriverLoadTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5434/IKOffice_Core", "ik", "ik0000");
        System.out.println(c.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName());
    }

}
```

Comment: However, your application needs to be properly documented that the enduser should be providing a full JDBC 4 compatible driver utilizing this [`java.util.ServiceLoader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) feature, else the application may not work. As far now not all major JDBC driver vendors have implemented this. I would still rely on `Class#forName()` and reevaluate the JDBC driver world after one year or two before entirely killing the `Class#forName()`.

Answer (score 1):

Often, you can just create an instance of it, but that results in a hard dependency on a particular driver.

The reason what Class.forName is used is because you can make it configurable. The reason it works is because it triggers the class's static initializers to run, which allow it to register with jdbc.

In short, as far as I'm aware, you have two options:

- Class.forName - allows configurable driver - nice
- direct instantiation - creates solid class dependency - not nice

Answer (score 1):

You can also add the driver class to the system property `jdbc.drivers` which is a list of colon-separated driver classnames that the `DriverManager` class loads.

Example:

```
java -Djdbc.drivers=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver MyApp
```

Source: The [DriverManager javadocs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver dr = null;